# jQuery used on Extended Form elements: multiselect

Tags: jquery, forms, multi-select

Looking for name of jQuery used on Extended Form elements: multiselect for admin template below:
http://www.eakroko.de/neat/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the source of that page and try and figure out which plugin was used. What i did:

1. Scrolled to the element of interest, in this case the multiselect field.
2. Right click on element, then selected *inspect element* option.
3. Figured out the class of that element : `<div id="select5_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi chzn-container-active" style="width: 384px;">`
4. Guessed that it was [chosen.jquery.min.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), because it was the closest match to the `chzn` class.

In the future repeat the above steps to figure out such things. *Inspect element* option or its equivalents are available in most browsers, if not natively, then atleast with web developer browser plugins.

Comment: Thanks for let me know the step. I did install chosen.jquery before but never think it can do such feature. I will study it again.

Comment: Yes it is Chosen. I thought it was Choose jQuery so never take a look at it although I did know the author use Chosen.